# Electronics/Physics related question which is mostly mathematics - on topic here?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I have a question which is related to a physical topic (force of one charge on another).
In fact this specific question is about a charged ring with a radius $R$ and a charge in z-direction in distance $d$.
The approach here would be to find an equation / integral based on these vectors (don't want to be too specific as this question is "meta").
Intuitively I'd ask this question here because it's mostly calculating with vectors but as it's also physics related, so I'm uncertain about where to ask this question.

Answer (score 10):

Physics questions are allowed here, but the questions have to be about the math behind the physics, e.g. "how does this equation for this particle yield this result?" as opposed to "what laws of physics apply to this situation?" So, to make sure your E&M question is on topic, include all the relevant physical equations as context, so that the answer you request can be deduced using only tools from mathematics.